# Compiler Design: How do you distinguish between "op_Minus number" and "negativeNumber"?

Tags: compiler-construction, language-design, compiler-theory

How do you distinguish between the token sequence "op_Minus" "number" and simple a negative number?

Comment: It depends on what came before it. Could you give an example?

Comment: I guess looking at the previous token would work.

Comment: Nitpicking: Most languages don't have negative numbers as such, only unary `-` (negation) that happens to be commonly applied to literals.

Comment: What stage of compilation are you in? Are you trying lex (create tokens from raw text), parse (create an abstract syntax tree from tokens), or generate code?

Comment: Halfway between lexing and parsing. My first thought was to have a fix-up pass that runs over the token stream just before parsing begins.

Comment: @Jonathan Allen, it's ok to do it while parsing. Represent negative constants as unary_minus(constant), and evaluate all the constant expressions prior to your code generation pass. And, by the way, most of the lexing-related problems will disappear if you don't have a lexing pass at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think it's context dependent and dependent on the number of operands you encounter while parsing the source code.

Depending on the type of syntax you choose/encounter, you either have something like this when you're dealing with subtraction:

```
operand1 - operand2
```

or if your language uses prefix notation, you'll end up with something like this:

```
- operand1 operand2
(- operand1 operand2)
```

In both cases you should be able to either deduce from the previous token (in the case of infix notation) or from the lookahead to the next token/next two tokens) if you're dealing with a subtraction or a negative number, given that the latter would only have a single operand.